# Javascript Illegal Token Error

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

Forgive me if this is a simple problem but I can't seem to find why this code:

```
function create_content(c)
        {
            var html = "<div id='header'>"+c+"</div>";
            if(c == "links")
            {
                var ul = "<ul><li><a href='http://www.mylink.com'>My Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.mylink2.co.uk'>My Link 2</a></li></ul>";
                html = html + ul;
            }
            return(html);
        }
```

Is giving me this error in Chrome (win):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

On the line that starts with "var ul = "

Any advice would help thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are inserting a line break in your `ul` string, between the closing `</li>` and the opening `<li>`. JavaScript string literals cannot span multiple lines like this by themselves, unless you

- Trail a `\` at each line but the last (as Ivo Wetzel says):

  ```
  var ul = "<ul><li><a href='http://www.mylink.com'>My Link 1</a></li>\
  <li><a href='http://www.mylink2.co.uk'>My Link 2</a></li></ul>";
  ```
- Break them and concatenate the parts, like this:

  ```
  var ul = "<ul><li><a href='http://www.mylink.com'>My Link 1</a></li>";
  ul += "<li><a href='http://www.mylink2.co.uk'>My Link 2</a></li></ul>";
  ```

  (To keep the newline there you would place a `\n` somewhere, but in HTML it won't matter.)

Comment: Wrong. They can span multiple lines, just add a trailing `\\` at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I found I needed to escape the forward slashes in my closing tags. ie;

```
<\/script>
```

or

```
<\/form>
```

Then the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" Error went away and my code processed fine.