# Unexpected token Illegal

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I know there are other similar question related on stack overflow, but none seemed to correct my problem. This error occur on every browser (although I used webkit error name).

I need to add javascript using PHP. This cause the error "Unexpected token illegal" to appear. I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4635492/1202691) without success. This is what I have now :

```
    $texte .="<script>";
    $texte .="$(function(){";
    $texte .="$('#field_".$this->id."').css('position','absolute').css('left','".$this->x."px').css('top','".$this->y."px');";
    $texte .="$('#field_".$this->id."').draggable({stop:function(event,ui){saveFieldPosition(".$this->id.");},grid:[10,10],containment:\".work_plane:first\"}).resizable({grid:[10,10]});";
    $texte .="});";
    $texte .="</script>";

    return $texte;
```

I have enabled Dreamweaver hidden characters and remove every one that would be in $texte value.

Anyone sees the problem? Any hint would be appreciated.

Edit: the $texte is passed trough htmlentities() before it's added.

Here's the output :

```
    &lt;script&gt;$(function(){$('#field_1').css('position','absolute').css('left','px').css('top','px');$('#field_').draggable({stop:function(event,ui){saveFieldPosition();},grid:[10,10],containment:&quot;.work_plane:first&quot;}).resizable({grid:[10,10]});});&lt;/script&gt;
```

Comment: Can you update your question with what appears in the source after the page has loaded?  It would be a lot easier to scan through that, and if some of your object properties are undefined, there would be no way to know from what you have posted.

Comment: Can you include the code that evaluates to after php processing?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to separate your string like that.  Also, you can use [`HEREDOC`](http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-heredoc-syntax.html)

```
$texte .= <<<JAVASCRIPT
   <script language="javascript">
       $(function() {
           $('#field_{$this->id}').css('position','absolute').css('left','{this->x}px').css('top','{$this->y}px');
           $('#field_{$this->id}').draggable({
                   stop:function(event,ui){
                           saveFieldPosition({$this->id});
                       },
                   grid:[10,10],
                   containment: ".work_plane:first"
               }).resizable({
                   grid:[10,10]
               });
       });
    </script>
JAVASCRIPT;
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

the " " after containment should be single quotes ' ' with no escapes -

```
$texte .="$('#field_".$this->id."').draggable({stop:function(event,ui){saveFieldPosition(".$this->id.");},grid:[10,10],containment:'.work_plane:first'}).resizable({grid:[10,10]});";
```

this preserves a syntactically correct JS output by PHP

You've got doublequotes " starting the the line. You can then use single quotes internally without having to escape them.

```
"foo:'bar'"
```

is the same as

```
"foo:\"bar\""
```

Comment: .work_plane:first is a css selector, I need it to be a string

Comment: then change the " " double quotes to ' ' single quotes? `$texte .="$('#field_".$this->id."').draggable({stop:function(event,ui){saveFieldPosition(".$this->id.");},grid:[10,10],containment:'.work_plane:first'}).resizable({grid:[10,10]});";`